# Finding either foo or bar with Linq extensions

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object "IdentityProvider" and "IdentityProvider" has child Domains.

```
class IdentityProvider
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Domain
{
    ...
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

There is a catch all domain called "*"

Using Linq Extensions, I need to find all the IdentityProviders that have either the specified domain, or IdentityProviders that have the catch all, but nor both.

How would I form my query?

Comment: How `IdentityProvider` looks? Type definition? Any code you have already tried..?

Comment: @RahulSingh Added class definition... I have tried lots of combinations but nothing that works anywhere close at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those that answered, you helped me in other areas, but for this question I ended up doing the following, probably not the best way, but it works:

See if the domain exists:

```
var domExists = db.Domains.Any(d => d.Name == domain);
```

Find all the identity providers where domain exists AND domExists OR find wildcard and not domExists.

```
IdentityProviders.Where(d => 
    d.Domains.Any(n => n.Name == domain && domExists) || 
    d.Domains.Any(n => n.Name == "*" && !domExists)
).Any()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should make it:

```
from i in identityProviders
let hasDomain = i.Domains.Any(d => d.Name == domainName)
let hasCatchAll = i.Domains.Any(d => d.Name == "*")
where (hasDomain && !hasCatchAll) || (!hasDomain && hasCatchAll)
select i;
```

You could try using [XOR (`^`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) instead in `where` clause:

```
from i in identityProviders
let hasDomain = i.Domains.Any(d => d.Name == domainName)
let hasCatchAll = i.Domains.Any(d => d.Name == "*")
where hasDomain ^ !hasCatchAll
select i;
```

but I'm not sure if it get's translated into SQL by your provider (you didn't specify what kind of LINQ source you're dealing with...).

Comment: They are very nearly there but the catchall is also returned when there is a domain match.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can't be checked with standard LINQ functions, without iterating the `Domains` collection twice which is needlessly inefficient. I would use a custom filter function like this, iterating once and failing early if both are found:

```
identityProviders.Where(identityProvider => {
    bool hasDomain = false, hasCatchAll = false;
    foreach (var domain in identityProvider.Domains) {
        hasDomain = hasDomain || domain.Name == domainName;
        hasCatchAll = hasCatchAll || domain.Name == "*";
        if (hasDomain && hasCatchAll) return false;
    }
    return hasDomain || hasCatchAll;
})
```

Comment: I'm probably not using this correctly as i get an error: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: @Jamie It's because you're using Entity Framework and it's trying to convert the query to SQL, so you can't use this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you group your data by domains which have the catch all such as:

```
var grouped = ipProviders.Domains
                         .GroupBy (dm => dm.Name == "*");
```

Then you can either return all the catch alls at once or extract the target domains with the exact name such as

```
var targetDomain = "Jabberwocky";

var targets = grouped.Where (gr => gr.Key == (targetDomain == "*"))
                     .Select (gr => gr.Where (dm => dm.Name == targetDomain));
```

The grouping looks like this with data of `Jabberwocky`, `OmegaMan` and two domains with `*`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer you gave doesn't give you what you asked for in the question. You said you wanted providers that had one or the other but not both.

First, if a provider has both, it *will* be selected by this code because the first condition is true:

```
d.Domains.Any(n => n.Name == domain && domExists)
```

Second, if a provider has the catch-all but NOT the specified domain, it will *not* be selected if the domain does exist in a *different* provider. This is because `domExists` will be true, so the second check will fail:

```
d.Domains.Any(n => n.Name == "*" && !domExists)
```

I don't see how capturing the `domExists` flag can really help you. However, I think starting by searching the entire collection of domains is the right idea. You could try this:

First, collect all the IDs of providers for domains that match either "*" or the name (I assume Domain must have a foreign key to IdentityProvider):

```
var providerIds =
    db.Domains.Where(d => d.Name == domain || d.Name == "*")
    .Select(d => d.IdentityProviderID)
    .ToList();
```

This narrows it down quite a lot, and we have a way of filtering it again: Any providers that have *both* will have been added to the list twice, so we just need to select all the IDs that only appear once:

```
var uniqueProviderIds =
    providerIds.GroupBy(id => id)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Now `uniqueProviderIds.Any()` will give you your answer. You can also use this list to build another SQL query to get the actual IdentityProvider objects if you need them:

```
db.IdentityProviders.Where(ip => uniqueProviderIds.Contains(ip.ID)).ToList()
```

Answer (score -1):

please try

```
identityProviders.Where(ip=>ip.Domains.Any(d=>d.Name=="SearchDomain" || d.Name=="*"))
```